# Why is nvarchar column saving number to exponential number in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, exponential

Please help. I have recently migrated a database from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2019.

My code extracts an invoice number from an Oracle linked server and saves it to an `nvarchar(20)` column.

The problem is after the migration, all invoice numbers are saved as exponential numbers.

For example: `62814700023` becomes `6.28147e+008`.

The problem is I am unable to convert the exponential value back to a numeric because I lose digits in the process.

This is confusing as both databases have the exact same code and table structure. Is this related to server settings or version? If so, how can I fix it without having to change my data type to avoid subsequent code fixes?

Comment: Not related, but _The problem is I am unable to convert the exponential value back to a numeric_ - If you use originally numeric value as a number, why you saving it as a varchar? Can you save as a number?

Comment: e-notation often happens when `float` values get converted to character types. e.g. `declare @float float = 62814700023; select cast(@float as nvarchar(20));` Is the invoice number column in the source database a `float` column (or was it cast to `float` in the select query that was extracting the data)?

Comment: @Fabio because the source column can have both numeric and non numeric. So invoice number can be either 123456 or abc1234. So we set the type to varchar to accomodate both

Comment: @AlwaysLearning no cast is used either the select query or the insert. As i mentioned, this wasnt a problem in the original database and i made no changes. Not sure why the conversion is a problem in the 2019 version.

Comment: How did you transfer the data from the source table to the destination table? You mention "my code" so can you show us any of that?

Comment: Ok, from old database to new database i did a backup and restore.

Comment: For the actual data, no change, I use an openquery starting like:
Set @SQL = '
Insert into [STAGING] select *  from openquery ([Linkedserver], "
SELECT DISTINCT ooha.INV_number,
                haou.attribute5 ORG,
                ooha.country,
    mc.type ..... ")